# Proper way to compare two objects of different types

Tags: c#, equality

I'm using a lib containing a service that notifies when an object is created or deleted in another application. Those object are of type A which contains a lot of information that I don't need in my app.

So in my app I created a type B which is a lightweight A type. When I get notified by the service that an object A has been deleted, I have to match the deleted item from type A with my type B to delete the right object.

Should I override the type B Equals method and write something like:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    if (base.Equals(obj)) return true; //check for reference
    B lightweightObj = obj as B;

    if (alarm == null) {
        A objFromService = obj as A;
        if (objFromService == null) return false;
        return objFromService.Class == this.ClassId &&
                objFromService.Group == this.GroupId &&
                objFromService.Name.Equals(this.Name) &&
                objFromService.Time == this.Time &&
                objFromService.Projectname.Equals(this.Project.Project.Name);
    } else {
        return lightweightObj.ClassId == this.ClassId &&
               lightweightObj.GroupId == this.GroupId &&
               lightweightObj.Name.Equals(this.Name) &&
               lightweightObj.Time == this.Time &&
               lightweightObj.Project == this.Project;
    }
}
```

Or should I create a simple function taking a A typed object in parameter and returning a boolean?

I want to be able to do something like :

```
B matchingBObject = MyObjects.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Equals(args.TheAObject));
if(matchingBObject != null) {
    MyObjects.Remove(matchingBObject);
}
```

Should the Equals function only compare two object of the same type or is it alright to compare two types that are not related in any way?

Comment: If the types are not related in any way, what meaning does comparison hold?

Comment: @shree.pat18 like I said, the B type is a lightweight A type. They're not related in the way that B doesn't extend A and their only common ancestor type is Object

Comment: I think the point of Equals taking an Object parameter is that you can compare anything (or if it isn't, it seems to me like a reasonable use of it). But don't you think you should use some kind of inheritance here ?

Comment: I find your proposed usage of `Equals` confusing and unexpected and in my oppinion your code would be easier to understand if you create a method on B to compare it to A and use that instead.

Comment: @MickaelV. I think that the type of the parameter (Object) comes from the Object type. I can't make the B type inherit from A because it would contain at least as much information as type A and I want the type B to contain way less information than type A.

Comment: @MartinLiversage That's what I thought. The reason that Equals takes an Object as parameter doesn't mean we should pass any type to the function, it's of Object type only because Equals comes from Object type. I wanted to know if it was alright to do it, and if not why is it bad. So it's only a confusion problem in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely should not do it this way. Instead, as you suggested, you should simply write this logic as a separate method.

At the very least, code like this would be confusing, which leads to bugs, bugs that are usually hard to fix because no one else looking at the code (or you in six months) would ever guess someone would do something like this.

More problematic is that as most humans understand the concept of equality, it's reflexive. That is, if object A equals object B, then object B equals object. But if you set up an override like this, that won't be true. Instead, even if `a.Equals(b)` is `true`, it's possible that `b.Equals(a)` won't be.

Again, at the very least this is confusing. But it is even worse if you wind up trying to use this kind of implementation in, for example, a hash table or try to find an element in a list or other collection, that sort of thing. These are scenarios where the reflexive nature of equality is assumed and relied upon, and code like the above simply won't even work.

Please, for your own sanity and for the sanity of others, just write a regular method to make this determination, such as `LightweightMatchesServiceObject()` or something clear and understandable like that.